# iPhone SDK - CGBitmapContextCreate

Tags: iphone, uiimage, cgbitmapcontextcreate

I would like to create an image of my own. I already know its width (320*2 = 640) and height (427).

So I have some raw data :

```
unsigned char *rawImg = malloc(height * width * 4 *2 );
```

Then, I will fill it :)

Then, I have to do something like that to get a bitmap and return a (UIImage *) :

```
ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawImg,width*2,height,8,
    ???,
    ???,
    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast); 

UIImage * imgFinal = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx)];
CGContextRelease(ctx); 



return imgFinal;
```

But I don't know how to create my context ctx, as you can see with the "???", even tough I read the documentation...

Please help ! 
Thanks :)

Comment: So sorry, it isn't very clear but in this case width = 320, that's why I'm using "width*2", because my final image will be of width 640.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know but I just corrected it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See Apple's [CGBitmapContext documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html).

If you are using 4 bytes per pixel, then your bytes per row might be your half_width * 2 * 4.

Color space might be:

```
CGColorSpaceRef    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the current `CGContextRef` using

`CGContextRef context =`[`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext)